# webpack-bundle-tracker not creating webpack-stats.json?

Tags: python, node.js, django, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to use Vue and Django together as described in [this article](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-django-best-of-both-frontends-701307871478). Everything seems to be working except for the webpack-bundle-tracker. I'm pretty sure that webpack-bundle-tracker is not even installed as this happens when I run `yarn add webpack-bundle-tracker --dev`:

```
yarn add v1.22.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/core-js: self signed certificate in certificate chain".
```

However when I run `npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-tracker` it seems to work? but nothing really changes and no webpack-stats.json file is generated.

The other thing could be the django-webpack-loader, as when I ran `pip install django-webpack-loader` gives off a bunch of permissions errors, but it worked when I ran `pip install django-webpack-loader --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org`.

The error django gives me when I try to open my vue/django test page:

```
Error reading /Users/$ME/Dev/digiproj/vue_frontend/webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
```

Just not sure where to go from here and would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, also running Django with django-webpack-loader, and I also found that the webpack-stats.json file was not being generated. I fixed it by downgrading webpack-bundle-tracker to 0.4.3. I'm not sure why the latest version of this package does not work.

Comment: Dude you are awesome! I have been trying to solve this for days and now it's finally working - thank you so much!

Comment: @azwier , What is your django-webpack-loader version? is it possible attach your vue.config.js content?

Answer (score 0):

I've made certain changes and downgrading webpack-bundle-tracker from alpha to 0.4.3
You can find here [webpack-bundle-tracker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-tracker/v/0.4.3)

or install using **npm i webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3**

create vue.config.js file in frontend.

```
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
    publicPath: "http://0.0.0.0:8080",
    // output dir default buldle file ocation in dist
    outputDir: "./dist/",

    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.optimization.splitChunks(false)

        config.plugin('BundleTracker').use(BundleTracker, [
            {
                // filename: './webpack-stats.json'
                filename: './webpack-stats.json'
            }
        ])

        config.resolve.alias.set('__STATIC__', 'static')

        config.devServer
            .public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')
            .host('0.0.0.0')
            .port(8080)
            .hotOnly(true)
            .watchOptions({poll: 1000})
            .https(false)
            .headers({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ['\*']})
    }
};
```

And in django settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webpack_loader',
]
```

Add these configuration at the bottom of the settings.py file

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'CACHE': not DEBUG,
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'webpack_bundles/', # must end with slash
        'STATS_FILE': str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('frontend', 'webpack-stats.json')),
        'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
        'TIMEOUT': None,
        'IGNORE': [r'.+\.hot-update.js', r'.+\.map'],        
    }
}
```

And index.html looks like this,

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Django Vue-3X iNTEGRATION</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HELLO FROM DJANGO</h1>

    <div id="app">
        <h1>HELLO FROM Vue</h1>
    </div>

    {% render_bundle 'app' %}
</body>
</html>
```

These solved my problem.
And I also want help for using latest version of webpack-bundle-tracker with vueCli

Comment: I get **options has an unknown property 'watchOptions'.**